# check if div contains an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm bulding some drag and drop widgets in jQuery, once they've been dropped I need to check if my drag and droppable widget are inside another div.

```
<div id="droptarget">
    <div class="widget">I'm a widget!</div>
</div>
```

I've had a look at `$('#droptarget').each` but can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to select the outer div:

```
$("#droptarget:has(div.widget)")
```

If you want to select the widget:

```
$("#droptarget > div.widget")
```

Comment: Does it return a true/false so it can be used with an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with

```
if ($ ('#droptarget .widget')) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: $('#droptarget .widget') would always return an object, hence evaluate to true. You'd want to check if ($('#droptarget .widget').length > 0)

Comment: Remember 0 == false, so just ($("#myId").length) will work too.