# jQuery: check if a div contains a div with class on

Tags: jquery

I have several `<div>` elements inside another `<div>`.

I want to do an `if` statement which is *true* if a div inside the top div contains class on.

HTML:

```
<div class="toDiv">
    <div>

    </div>
    <div class="on">

    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($(".toDiv").contains("on")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892329/check-if-div-contains-an-element-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: do you have several divs with class `toDiv`?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
if ($(".toDiv").find(".on").length > 0){ 
  ///do something
}
```

or

```
if ($(".toDiv .on").length > 0){ 
  ///do something
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$('div.toDiv').each(function() {
    if($('div.on', this).length > 0) {
        //do something with this
    }
});
```